# Determine type and brand of Bluetooth card in laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bluetooth

I'm working on migrating my Windows 7 machine over to Linux and I'm researching compatibility. I've been able to determine the main things such as my video card, processor, storage, WiFi card, etc. but I haven't been able to determine what make and model my Bluetooth card is.

Is there a way to quickly and easily determine the make and model of my Bluetooth card in Windows 7?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/159068/23133

Comment: Open up your computer and look on the chip itself.   Should be easy enough to locate.

Comment: @Ramhound It's a laptop and I'm at work on my first day... don't think that would give the best impression ;)

Comment: @techie007 All I see under Hardware Ids is `BTH\MS_BTHPAN`, which doesn't seem to be so descriptive. Is there a shell command I could run to determine it?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay What's the laptop exact model? Was the Bluetooth turned on when you checked the hardware IDs in the Device Manager?